# SQL getting balance point of two cumulative sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

Bellow I provide a code, which does the job on this interesting task to some extent, but may be poorly designed due to my SQL knowledge limits. The main problem is, that the query gives *random* (more exactly 3 different) results when executed. My guess is, that the rows within nested queries get ordered by "randomly" selected column and that is why the final result is different (balance point is order-dependent).

The inner `SELECT` with `GROUP` creates a list of r-dates and two cumulative sums, such as this:

```
rIndex  r             TotalPerDay   CumulativeSum1  CumulativeSum2
1       02.05.2019    92,81         92,81           0
2       03.05.2019    24,81         117,61          0
3       06.05.2019    43,79         161,40          60
4       07.05.2019    78,65         240,05          120
5       09.05.2019    33,99         274,04          180
6       10.05.2019    73,22         347,26          240
7       13.05.2019    19,24         366,50          300
8       14.05.2019    150,77        517,27          360
9       15.05.2019    22,69         539,95          420
10      16.05.2019    4,96          544,91          480
11      17.05.2019    17,45         562,36          540
12      20.05.2019    27,19         589,55          600
13      21.05.2019    12,45         602,00          660
14      22.05.2019    18,08         620,08          720
15      23.05.2019    3,49          623,57          780
16      24.05.2019    10,51         634,09          840
17      27.05.2019    6,19          640,28          900
18      28.05.2019    3,01          643,29          960
19      29.05.2019    2,68          645,97          1020
20      30.05.2019    184,51        830,48          1080
```

An attempt for sample data is in an attachment (removed due to comment bellow).

In the 2nd nested `SELECT` I find a balance-point, which is a (first) date, where `CumulativeSum1 > CumulativeSum2`. I then have to find an index of days with sums (because there are also days without data) and that is the final result; it's the top-most `SELECT` in the query bellow:

```
DECLARE @eDate as Date
DECLARE @DayLimit INT
SET @DayLimit = 60  -- let's assume a constant here
SET @eDate = DATEFROMPARTS('2019','05','31')

-- get balance point INDEX over non-empty days
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(cDate) FROM Calendar WHERE KindOfDay = 'BANKDAY' AND cDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND SRC3.BalanceDate) as rIndex
FROM
    (    
    SELECT TOP 1 SRC2.rDate   -- get first balance point (date)
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SRC.rDate) as RowNo
            ,SRC.rDate 
            ,SRC.TotalPerDay      -- not required for processing, included just for info and check
            ,(SELECT (SUM((eTime-ISNULL(rDura,0))/60)) FROM MyTable1 as MT WHERE MT.r <= SRC.rDate AND MT.r < @eDate)         as CumulativeSum1
            ,((SELECT COUNT(cDate) FROM Calendar WHERE KindOfDay = 'BANKDAY' AND cDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND SRC.rDate) * @DayLimit) as CumulativeSum2
        FROM (
            SELECT   
                  CASE  
                      WHEN CAST(r as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date)  
                      THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))                
                      ELSE CAST(r as date)                           
                  END as rDate, 
                  SUM((eTime-ISNULL(rDura,0))/60) as TotalPerDay      
            FROM MyTable1 
            WHERE r < @eDate
            GROUP BY  -- group by non-empty dates, group all past dates to yesterday
                   CASE  
                       WHEN CAST(r as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date)  
                      THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))               
                      ELSE CAST(r as date)                             
                   END                                
        ) as SRC                          
        --ORDER BY rDate
        ) as SRC2  -- compiled list of sums per day
    WHERE SRC2.CumulativeSum2 > SRC2.CumulativeSum1;    -- balance condition
) as SRC3
```

I humbly ask for suggestions for the obvious issues:

- how could I ensure order of rows in the nested query to get reliable result?
- are there obvious mistakes in my query design and how to improve it?

Also, I just realized there's a discrepancy in the topmost query, where I get index over bank days, hower the index should be over non-empty bank days...

Some sample data:

```
-------  CALENDAR TABLE  --------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [cDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [KindOfDay] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Calendar] ([cDate],[KindOfDay])  VALUES 
    ('2019-04-20 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-04-21 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-04-22 00:00:00.000', 'HOLIDAY'),
    ('2019-04-23 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-04-24 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-04-25 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-04-26 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-04-27 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-04-28 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-04-29 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-04-30 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-01 00:00:00.000', 'HOLIDAY'),
    ('2019-05-02 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-03 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-04 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-05-06 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-07 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-08 00:00:00.000', 'HOLIDAY'),
    ('2019-05-09 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-10 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-11 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-05-12 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-05-13 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-14 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-15 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-16 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-17 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-18 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-05-19 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-05-20 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-21 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-23 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-24 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-25 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-05-26 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-05-27 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-28 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-29 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-30 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-05-31 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-01 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-06-02 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-06-03 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-04 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-05 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-06 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-07 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-08 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-06-09 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-06-10 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-11 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-12 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-13 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-14 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-15 00:00:00.000', 'SATURDAY'),
    ('2019-06-16 00:00:00.000', 'SUNDAY'),
    ('2019-06-17 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-18 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-19 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY'),
    ('2019-06-20 00:00:00.000', 'BANKDAY')
GO



-------  MyTable1 TABLE  --------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable1](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [eTime] [decimal](12,6) NOT NULL,
    [rDura] [date] NULL
) 



INSERT INTO MyTable1 (ID, rDura, eTime, rDate) VALUES
    (17008431,NULL,0.1855,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17008477,NULL,0.059,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17008500,NULL,0.329667,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17090449,NULL,3.3195,'2019-05-02'), 
    (16888594,NULL,13.830667,'2019-04-26'), 
    (16888681,NULL,12.6635,'2019-04-26'), 
    (16888722,NULL,8.154667,'2019-05-07'), 
    (16888750,NULL,7.83,'2019-05-07'), 
    (16888766,NULL,5.22,'2019-05-07'), 
    (16955798,NULL,12.35,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17108201,NULL,1.669833,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17110834,NULL,2.596667,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17111001,NULL,0.814667,'2019-05-06'), 
    (16893842,NULL,1.053,'2019-05-07'), 
    (16951779,NULL,2.720833,'2019-05-03'), 
    (16951821,NULL,4.042333,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17017058,NULL,0.227333,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17017060,NULL,1.06,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17017066,NULL,1.869333,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17019289,NULL,0.835667,'2019-04-26'), 
    (17020295,NULL,3.983333,'2019-04-21'), 
    (17106404,105,3.3545,'2019-04-29'), 
    (17107843,NULL,2.815167,'2019-05-07'), 
    (16725584,NULL,0.693,'2019-04-25'), 
    (17101197,NULL,3.906667,'2019-04-30'), 
    (17101993,NULL,0.571667,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17102225,NULL,3.048833,'2019-04-30'), 
    (17102482,NULL,7.5945,'2019-05-10'), 
    (16974196,NULL,1.633333,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17113406,NULL,0.871833,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17113408,NULL,0.749833,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17113784,NULL,1.961333,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17120601,NULL,4.033333,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17120609,NULL,3.983333,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17120618,NULL,2.626667,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17120626,NULL,2.64,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17120628,NULL,3.684167,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17121720,NULL,2.235,'2019-04-30'), 
    (17058455,NULL,5.806667,'2019-04-29'), 
    (17059476,NULL,2.264833,'2019-05-22'), 
    (17059478,NULL,182.603667,'2019-05-30'), 
    (17065386,NULL,5.539667,'2019-05-10'), 
    (16927091,NULL,1.381,'2019-05-14'), 
    (16927093,NULL,112.304685,'2019-05-14'), 
    (16991456,NULL,0.931667,'2019-04-29'), 
    (17122394,NULL,1.560167,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17126711,NULL,4.046,'2019-05-03'), 
    (16935823,NULL,0.359,'2019-04-25'), 
    (17069727,NULL,1.952833,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17069870,NULL,1.742333,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17070555,NULL,5.416667,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17070557,NULL,3.894167,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17070851,NULL,2.64,'2019-04-23'), 
    (17073724,NULL,0.737667,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17074763,NULL,1.413833,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17131824,NULL,4.258,'2019-05-10'), 
    (17132133,NULL,0.257667,'2019-05-14'), 
    (17132865,NULL,2.769833,'2019-05-17'), 
    (17138082,NULL,7.866667,'2019-05-31'), 
    (17139196,NULL,5.860167,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17139200,NULL,1.479667,'2019-05-03'), 
    (16983337,NULL,2.951667,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17028542,NULL,0.680333,'2019-05-13'), 
    (16823160,NULL,5,'2019-05-06'), 
    (16823168,NULL,5,'2019-05-06'), 
    (16823182,NULL,5,'2019-05-06'), 
    (16823192,NULL,5,'2019-05-06'), 
    (16906776,NULL,0.8635,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17082286,NULL,3.333333,'2019-05-09'), 
    (17083776,NULL,2.317167,'2019-04-25'), 
    (17083778,NULL,1.447167,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17084568,NULL,0.2375,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17154415,NULL,2.64,'2019-05-14'), 
    (17154425,NULL,2.626667,'2019-05-14'), 
    (17154453,NULL,0.052,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17155029,NULL,3.256667,'2019-05-22'), 
    (17157159,NULL,1.333333,'2019-05-15'), 
    (16994233,NULL,0.252167,'2019-04-29'), 
    (17039767,NULL,1.401667,'2019-05-10'), 
    (17040346,NULL,4.021667,'2019-05-09'), 
    (17040815,NULL,1.2675,'2019-05-16'), 
    (17042063,NULL,0.213333,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17050144,NULL,0.976667,'2019-05-02'), 
    (17050150,NULL,0.837167,'2019-05-20'), 
    (17051422,NULL,1.826,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17142464,NULL,0.464333,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17145501,NULL,4.745333,'2019-06-06'), 
    (17145980,NULL,0.195167,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17145999,NULL,1.330833,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17146001,NULL,1.503833,'2019-05-06'), 
    (17146011,NULL,1.22,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17146017,NULL,0.373,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17146023,NULL,0.5745,'2019-05-03'), 
    (17146127,NULL,1.7835,'2019-05-15'), 
    (17146131,NULL,13.5595,'2019-05-07'), 
    (17152617,NULL,4.535667,'2019-05-10'), 
    (17154390,NULL,3.983333,'2019-05-14'), 
    (17154398,NULL,5.416667,'2019-05-14'), 
    (17154400,NULL,3.684167,'2019-05-14')

 GO
```

Comment: *"how could I ensure order of rows in the nested query to get reliable result?"* You can't order data within a subquery/CTE. If you need to maintain awareness of the order, you'll need to use `ROW_NUMBER` inside the subquery/CTE to provide the outer query with a value to order on. *Also, don't provide links to things like Google/One Drive, etc. Many volunteers won't click the link as we don't trust files from an anonymous stranger. If you need to include data/DDL/DML, etc, do you in your post as formatted `text`. Thanks.*

Comment: This seems a little meandering.

Comment: @Larnu: No problem with attached file, I can remove it. There's however recommended procedure in `SO META` post, which I followed. I also assumed that is what link feature is for. And the SQL is not downloaded directly, but displayed by GDrive first on the screen as a text file.
Regarding the `ROW_NUMBER()`, you must be right; I thought it would produce same effect, not realizing I can `ORDER` within `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: I added ROW_NUMBER() (shown in code above), but I don't get how to employ it, if one cannot use ORDER BY in nested queries. The added RowNo field itself doesn't help, of course.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 . . . I think you should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: I don't understand, why to post the same question again? And I actually included sample data, but was asked to remove it… (as a link). I can include it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested `ROW_NUMBER()` did not help to overcome the problém on it's own. I had to split task into two steps: Fist, I had to set a variable `@bDate` to store the result of the 2 inner nested `SELECT`s and subsequently find the index of this date in separate `SELECT` step.

```
DECLARE @eDate as Date
DECLARE @DayLimit INT
SET @DayLimit = 60  -- let's assume a constant here
SET @eDate = DATEFROMPARTS('2019','05','31')

-- get balance point INDEX over non-empty days    
SELECT TOP 1 @bDate = SRC2.rDate   -- get first balance point (date)
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SRC.rDate) as RowNo
        ,SRC.rDate 
        ,SRC.TotalPerDay      -- not required for processing, included just for info and check
        ,(SELECT (SUM((eTime-ISNULL(rDura,0))/60)) FROM MyTable1 as MT WHERE MT.r <= SRC.rDate AND MT.r < @eDate)         as CumulativeSum1
        ,((SELECT COUNT(cDate) FROM Calendar WHERE KindOfDay = 'BANKDAY' AND cDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND SRC.rDate) * @DayLimit) as CumulativeSum2
    FROM (
        SELECT   
                CASE  
                    WHEN CAST(r as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date)  
                    THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))                
                    ELSE CAST(r as date)                           
                END as rDate, 
                SUM((eTime-ISNULL(rDura,0))/60) as TotalPerDay      
        FROM MyTable1 
        WHERE r < @eDate
        GROUP BY  -- group by non-empty dates, group all past dates to yesterday
                CASE  
                    WHEN CAST(r as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date)  
                    THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))               
                    ELSE CAST(r as date)                             
                END                                
    ) as SRC                          
    --ORDER BY rDate
    ) as SRC2  -- compiled list of sums per day
WHERE SRC2.CumulativeSum2 > SRC2.CumulativeSum1;    -- balance condition

-- get the index of bank day from Today
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(cDate) FROM Calendar WHERE KindOfDay = 'BANKDAY' AND cDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @bDate);
```